# CSS box model issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to figure out the CSS for one of my projects.

I have a class 'header-container' applied to the div container which on checking is as follows -

[image: header-container-css]

[image: header-container-css-1]

I have a query on why are the contents of the 'wrapper' div which is the child of 'header-container' div, not entirely inside the content box (i.e. the blue highlighted box) and can be seen in the orange part.
Please find the CSS for the wrapper div below -

[image: wrapper-div]

[image: wrapper-div-1]

Why is the element CSS not following the CSS Box Model? and how can it be resolved?

Project is published on - https://surijatin.github.io/covid-second-dose/

Comment: Please see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code).

Comment: I forgot to add the link for the project. I have edited the description to include it now. You can check where it is published and work on directly on the problem instead of the minimal reproducible example. ;)

Comment: The problem is that you are setting a fixed height, so the content is overflowing instead of making the container grow. Just remove the `height` property and it should be fine, not sure why you need it

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it post your code here and create a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your image:

- `.header-container` has a specified height of 2vh. That's the height limit.
- So the text in `.wrapper` is simply overflowing that fixed height.

The orange sections are the 2vh top and bottom margins you've set.

Remove the `height: 2vh`, or switch to `min-height: 2vh`, and the problem should be resolved.